# Is there a closed form expression for integral $\int_{0}^a \frac{1}{x} \ln(x+1) dx$?

Tags: integration

Is there a closed form result for integral
$$
\int_{0}^a \frac{1}{x} \ln(x+1) dx
$$
where $a$ is a positive real value.

Comment: $$\int \frac{\ln(x+1)}{x} \, \mathrm{d}x = -\text{Li}_2(-x) + \mathrm{C}$$

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if this counts as a "closed form", but if $a\in(0,1)$ we have:

$$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx = \int_{0}^{a}\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} x^{n-1}}{n}\,dx = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n-1} a^n}{n^2}. \tag{1}$$
that can be written as $-\text{Li}_2(-a)=\text{Li}_2(a)-\frac{1}{2}\text{Li}_2(a^2).$

By taking the limit as $\alpha\to 1^-$ we also have $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx=\frac{\pi^2}{12}=\eta(2)=\frac{\zeta(2)}{2}.$

If $a>1$, we may use the [dilogarithm reflection formulas](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dilogarithm.html) to get:

$$ \int_{0}^{a}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\log^2(a)}{2}+\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2 a^n}.\tag{2} $$
Equivalently,
$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{a}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx &=& \frac{\pi^2}{12}+\int_{1}^{a}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx\\&=&\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\int_{\frac{1}{a}}^{1}\frac{\log(x+1)-\log(x)}{x}\,dx\\&=&\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\log^2(a)}{2}-\int_{0}^{\frac{1}{a}}\frac{\log(1+x)}{x}\,dx \end{eqnarray*}$$

proves the above reflection formula $(2)$ through $(1)$.

Comment: Dilogarithm has nice proprieties (+1)

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: *A mathematical function with the sense of humour* - D.Zagier

Comment: Thanks Jack I will download and read it tonight :)

Comment: @BehrouzMaleki: took from maths.dur.ac.uk/~dma0hg/dilog.pdf

Comment: :) so thanks my buddy.